# Load p tag from form using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to grap `p` tag from `form` tag but it is `null`:

```
string html = "<form id='foo123'> <p> loll </p> </form>";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[contains(@id, 'foo')]"); //.Count = 1
    var p = node[0].SelectSingleNode("./p"); // p is null
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue where the Agility Pack is incorrectly fixing the nesting of tags. You can work around it by calling:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
```

See: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/23074